# Bash Scripting not able to parse remote SSH commands correctly

Tags: bash, ssh, here-document

I'm trying to build a script to scp somefiles to another machine, but I'm trying to do some checkups before starting the actual SCP.

One of the checks is to see if there are somefiles (collectl raw files) on a remote host.

This is the part I have from my script:

```
ssh -T $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME bash << EOF

shopt -s nullglob
FILENAMES=( ${RAWDIR}/*${DATE}* )

if (( ${#FILENAMES[@]} )) && [[ -e ${FILENAMES[0]} ]]
then
  echo "At least one file matches the name" >&2
  exit 0
else
  echo "No files exist" >&2
  exit 1
fi

EOF
```

But I get this error:

```
tooladm@mxmcato01:tooladm/scripts> bash -x colplot.sh 20190201
+ PLOTDIR=/var/lib/zabbix/collectlfiles
+ RAWDIR=/opt/app/collectl
+ IMDG=3
+ HOSTNAME=mxmcaim03
+ USERNAME=abpdg3
+ DATE=20190201
+ SSH_CONN=zabbix@mxmcamon05
+ SEARCH_STRING='/opt/app/collectl/mxmcaim03-20190201*'
+ [[ 1 -ne 1 ]]
+ [[ 20190201 =~ ^[0-9]{8}$ ]]
+ date -d 20190201
+ is_valid=0
+ [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]
+ file_exists
+ ssh -T zabbix@mxmcamon05
FILES ARE NOT THERE, PROCEEDING WITH THE IMPORT
+ (( 0 ))
+ import_files
+ ssh -T abpdg3@mxmcaim03 bash
bash: line 5: unexpected argument `]]' to conditional unary operator
bash: line 5: syntax error near `]]'
bash: line 5: `if (( 0 )) && [[ -e  ]]'
```

What I had to do to make it work as expected is creating a second script the same hosts from where I'm executing this script and redirect its out to my ssh connection, like this:

```
lookup_remote_files()
{

ssh -T $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME "bash -s" < ./colplot_remote.sh "$DATE"

}

bash -x colplot.sh 20190201
+ PLOTDIR=/var/lib/zabbix/collectlfiles
+ RAWDIR=/opt/app/collectl
+ IMDG=3
+ HOSTNAME=mxmcaim03
+ USERNAME=abpdg3
+ DATE=20190201
+ SSH_CONN=zabbix@mxmcamon05
+ SEARCH_STRING='/opt/app/collectl/mxmcaim03-20190201*'
+ [[ 1 -ne 1 ]]
+ [[ 20190201 =~ ^[0-9]{8}$ ]]
+ date -d 20190201
+ is_valid=0
+ [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]
+ lookup_local_files
+ ssh -T zabbix@mxmcamon05
FILES ARE NOT THERE, PROCEEDING WITH THE IMPORT
+ (( 0 ))
+ lookup_remote_files
+ ssh -T abpdg3@mxmcaim03 'bash -s' 20190201
At least one file matches the name
+ (( 0 ))
```

I need to make this work from within the same script.

UPDATE:

The error is not there anymore, which I had also tried that, but it is not working as expected, for the date I'm using there are no files there:

```
tooladm@mxmcato01:tooladm/scripts> bash -x colplot.sh 20190205
+ PLOTDIR=/var/lib/zabbix/collectlfiles
+ RAWDIR=/opt/app/collectl
+ IMDG=3
+ HOSTNAME=mxmcaim03
+ USERNAME=abpdg3
+ DATE=20190205
+ SSH_CONN=zabbix@mxmcamon05
+ SEARCH_STRING='/opt/app/collectl/mxmcaim03-20190205*'
+ [[ 1 -ne 1 ]]
+ [[ 20190205 =~ ^[0-9]{8}$ ]]
+ date -d 20190205
+ is_valid=0
+ [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]
+ lookup_local_files
+ ssh -T zabbix@mxmcamon05
FILES ARE NOT THERE, PROCEEDING WITH THE IMPORT
+ (( 0 ))
+ lookup_remote_files
+ ssh -T abpdg3@mxmcaim03 bash
At least one file matches the name
+ (( 0 ))
```

Comment: If you're using `ssh ... <<EOF`, all the variables in the here-doc will be expanded on the local, not on the remote machine. Is that what you want? Try `ssh .. <<'EOF'` instead (single quotes around `EOF`).

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but given that I'm using some local variables as well, it doesn't work either. Thanks

Comment: Then you'll have to escape (`\$`) the variables that should be expanded on the remote machine.

Comment: I've also tried that, and nothing seems to work.

Comment: The error message shows that `${FILENAMES[0]}` is expanded to nothing on the *local* machine.

Comment: Yes, in fact I didn't notice, but also the first ${} is showing it has 0 files but those files are actually there, let me try scaping the dollar signs one more time

Comment: Have you considered using **`rsync`** which can check if the files that you intend to transfer exist and are up to date? I think `rsync` is a very powerful 'copy tool' that can work both via a network and locally.

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I was considering. But given that this is a production environment I do not have permission to use that, only in lower environments we are allowed to use it. Thanks.